# XSLT matching by attribute value of two different node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<Paragraph>
  <Span Text="This is " />
  <HyperlinkRangeStart AnnotationID="1">
    <HyperlinkInfo NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" />
  </HyperlinkRangeStart>
  <Span StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="Go" />
  <Span FontWeight="Bold" StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="o" />
  <Span StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="gle" />
  <HyperlinkRangeEnd AnnotationID="1" />
  <Span Text=" search engine" />
</Paragraph>
```

I want to transform it into a xhtml text as follows :

```
<p>This is <a href=http://www.google.com> [Go**o**gle][1]</a> search engine</p>
```

- Node:Span Attribute:Text between HyperlinkRangeStart AnnotationID="1" and HyperlinkRangeEnd AnnotationID="1" is the url content.
- Span Text above and below the HyperlinkRangeStart and HyperlinkRangeEnd will be a normal text.
- A Paragraph can have as many as URLs. Each URL range will have an unique AnnotationID.
- I don't know how to match by attribute id with different xml node.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "xhtml text". Please post your expected result **as code**. Also indicate if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: This is [Go**o**gle][1] search engine is the expected output.

Comment: You want the output method to be text?

Comment: Sorry, updated the expected output in the question.

Comment: Ok, then. Anytime you're ready to tell us your version of XSLT will be convenient.

Comment: Another sorry, using XSLT 1.0 (.Net framework 4.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly trivial, so let me take a slightly simplified input, albeit with multiple (two in my example) hyperlinks:

**Input:**

```
<Paragraph>
    <Span Text="This is " />
    <HyperlinkRangeStart AnnotationID="1">
        <HyperlinkInfo NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" />
    </HyperlinkRangeStart>
    <Span StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="Go" />
    <Span StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="o" />
    <Span StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="gle" />
    <HyperlinkRangeEnd AnnotationID="1" />
    <Span Text=" search engine. " />
    <Span Text="That is " />
    <HyperlinkRangeStart AnnotationID="2">
        <HyperlinkInfo NavigateUri="http://www.bing.com" />
    </HyperlinkRangeStart>
    <Span StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="Bi" />
    <Span StyleName="Hyperlink" Text="ng" />
    <HyperlinkRangeEnd AnnotationID="2" />
    <Span Text=" search motor." />
</Paragraph>
```

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="URLtext" match="Span[@StyleName='Hyperlink']" use="preceding-sibling::HyperlinkRangeStart[1]/@AnnotationID" />

<xsl:template match="Paragraph">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Span[not(@StyleName='Hyperlink')] | HyperlinkRangeStart"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="HyperlinkRangeStart">
    <a href="{HyperlinkInfo/@NavigateUri}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('URLtext', @AnnotationID)"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Span">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Text"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return this **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p>This is <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> search engine. That is <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a> search motor.</p>
```

The problem of formatting the hypertext link is left as an exercise for the reader.